# Are artificial dyes harmful to children?

Tags: pediatrics, artificial, children-kids, dyes, artificial-flavor

I've seen many claims online regarding artificial dyes causing problems such as ADD/ADHD in children, such as [this one from healthychild.org](http://www.donotlink.com/hnd8). Kraft recently [removed](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/morning-mix/wp/2015/04/21/kraft-mac-cheese-just-got-duller-you-can-thank-or-blame-the-food-babe/) artificial colors from their macaroni and cheese products.

What does the research say? Do artificial colors (in the concentrations seen in food and drink products) represent a risk to children?